macOS Ventura unable to auto source custom terminal settings (~/.zprofile)
I have a custom .bashrc file with loads of aliases and custom functions which is all located in ~/.bashrc. In ~/.zprofile I added source ~/.bashrc. All my functions and alias work except for the following.
autoload -U colors && colors
RPROMPT="%(?.%F{010}✔.%F{009}✗)%f"
NEWLINE=$'\n'
VALID="${NEWLINE}%F{009}┏━[%f%F{010}%n%f%F{011}@%f%F{014}%m%f%F{009}]–[%f%F{010}%~%f%F{009}]${NEWLINE}┗━━━▶%f%F{011} %(!.#.$)%f "
INVALID="${NEWLINE}%F{009}┏━[✗%f%F{white}]–[%F{010}%n%f%F{011}@%f%F{014}%m%f %F{009}]–[%f%F{010}%~%f%F{009}]${NEWLINE}┗━━━▶%f%F{011} %(!.#.$)%f "
PS1="%(?.$VALID.$INVALID)"
export PS1;
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxexcxdxbxegedabagacad

With the above code. I get the following error colors: function not defined by file
It then does not load the custom terminal look, until i actually manually have to type and source ~/.zprofile.
How do i get the terminal to load the custom look automatically without having to manually source ~/.zprofile. I know the bashrc file works as the aliases and custom functions all work.
The cool look comes from https://github.com/cfahd/parrotos-macos/blob/main/cfahd.txt
Which makes the terminal look like a ParrotSec terminal

I don‘t use zsh, but most likely autoload works differently than in bash.

You may have an extra file named colors in the FPATH (the path used to find autoload functions), ahead of the file supplied with zsh. You can list all of the matches in the fpath with ls -l ${^fpath}/colors(N.) - on my system, the function definition is in /usr/share/zsh/5.9/functions.

Did you ensure that your zsh is started as a login shell? If not, .zprofile won't be loaded automatically. Aside from this, I consider it pretty risky to use one common file for bash and zsh. It is easy to add something which works in one shell, but not in the other.

Adding to that comment - colours and prompt things should be in the interactive file for zsh - .zshrc not the login file .zprofile

@mmmmmm This worked. Simply moving it to the .zshrc file automatically loads the file, with colors.


Adding to that comment - colours and prompt things should be in the
interactive file for zsh - .zshrc not the login file .zprofile.
@mmmmmm

Adding the code to the ~/.zshrc file, It now automatically loads the colors and new style.
